# saving/loading binary compiled effect files in CG

Tags: opengl, cg

I'm working on NVidia CG. If I have created an effect from file using this line:

```
CGeffect basicEffect = cgCreateEffectFromFile( myContext,
                                               "Data/Shaders/basicEffect.cgfx",
                                                0);
```

Is there a way to save this effect (basicEffect) to a binary file in the compiled form.
So that if I want to create the effect later, I simply load the compiled effect file and 
assign it directly to basicEffect ???

Any help ?